# Segmentation Fault when reading from raw file

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc

I'm trying to read data from a raw file and storing them in a buffer of type char * that will then be stored in a jpg file and for some reason I keep getting a "Segmentation fault" error.

I'm using the malloc() function to allocate 512 bytes of memory for the buffer but I can only read up to 8 bytes at a time before I get the error (I'm trying to read 512 bytes at once).

Here's my code:

```
char *rawfilename = argv[1];

FILE *rawfile = fopen(rawfilename, "r");

if(rawfile == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", rawfilename);
    return 2;
}

char imgfilename[] = "image0.jpg";

FILE *imgfile = fopen(imgfilename, "w");

char *buffer = malloc(512 * sizeof(char));


//This works

fread(&buffer, 8, 1, rawfile);

fwrite(&buffer, 8, 1, imgfile);

/////////


//This doesn't work

fread(&buffer, 512, 1, rawfile);

fwrite(&buffer, 512, 1, imgfile);

/////////


free(buffer);

fclose(rawfile);

fclose(imgfile);
```

I've tried googling this problem and searching through Stack overflow but could not find anything that related to this specific issue so my apologies if something like this was already answered. I'm probably doing something stupid or not using something correctly.

Thanks

Comment: remove `&` before `buffer` in fread/fwrite

Comment: I tried that before and although I'm able to store more bytes, it only allows me to store up to 521 bytes. If I store anymore, I get this error: "free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x0000000002197490 ***". I would think I would get an error after storing more than 512 bytes but I don't until I get to 522. Would happen to know why? I just want to get a better understanding of how this works. Thanks!

Comment: If you ask 512 of memory, then that is what you get. So you can't store more there than those 512 bytes. What you do is like buying something without having enough money.

Comment: You get your error (if any) when the system has determined somthing is wrong. That can be immediately, later or even never (and never includes "no message but the wrong result")

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the *address of the pointer* rather than the *address which the pointer points to* into fwrite and fread which is causing undefined behaviour. You should pass the value of the pointer, i.e. the address to the block of memory you allocated, to the function.

It should be `fread(buffer, 8, 1, rawfile);` and not `fread(&buffer, 8, 1, rawfile);`

Your top example also does not work, undefined behaviour is just... well undefined. If you are lucky it crashes, if not you might get confused.

Answer (score 1):

The comment of Ilya Bursow gives you the answer.

However, the fact that the following works:

```
fread(&buffer, 8, 1, rawfile);
```

is beacuse you are on a 64 bit system where pointers are 64 bit. So you told `fread` to read 8 bytes and put that in the pointer, which is exactly 8 bytes...

And so, reading anything more than 8 bytes in this manner overwrites other memory, causing undefined behavior.

Lookup the descripion of `fread`. it will tell it needs a pointer to the memory, not the address of the pointer to memory (i.e. not a pointer to a pointer to memory). And since `buffer` is already  pointer, you only need to write `fread(buffer,...`

Comment: "reading anything more than 8 bytes in this manner overwrites other memory, causing undefined behavior." -- reading anything more than 0 bytes (i.e. reading anything at all) corrupts the pointer, which is later passed to `free` -- so there is undefined behavior either way.

Comment: @EmployedRussian, sure, but the `fread` worked (explaining his question).